# Firebase cloud messaging for push notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have to implement push notification to my application. The application need to show interviews for the current user at a particular time in a day. The application need to check an api to check whether there is interviews for today or not.
1) Can we make the fcm to check the api online and if only the interview is available(case of return object is not null) then only push the notification to the app?(checking the api through writing some codes to fcm console or linking the fcm with the backend)
2) Creating a service invoked by running a broadcast receiver linked with alarm manager to check the interviews in the web is a right way to do? Or can i invoke the api through fcm not involving the actions from android application?

NB: completely new to FCM push notifications, after so many search atlast i am posting here because I couldn't clear my query from the internet Please help
The web api is coming from an AWS server and the code of creation of api is in java.

Comment: FCM only sends messages to devices, it does not perform other tasks. If you want to send something to a device with specific logic you have to do that logic yourself and then tell FCM to alert the device you want

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement the logic in app itself.